# Algorithm to Convert Infix to LaTeX code in Java

Tags: java, latex, postfix-notation, infix-notation, rpn

I am trying to convert infix input like `x^2sin(pi/2)` to the appropriate LaTeX code like `x^2\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}` which I tried using [Shunting Yard algorithm](https://brilliant.org/wiki/shunting-yard-algorithm/) to initially convert infix to [postfix](https://github.com/kieferlam/postfix)*. But then I am not being able to convert the freshly prepared postfix to LaTeX code. I also tried to iterate through the infix and convert each fragment to LaTeX individually but soon realised that its very very inefficient and not worth it.

Here is my starter code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ShuntingYard {
    private enum Precedence {
        lparen(0), rparen(1), plus(2), minus(3), divide(4), times(5), mod(6), eos(7), operand(8);

        private int index;
        Precedence(int index) {
            this.index = index;
        }
        public int getIndex() {
            return index;
        }
    }
    /** in stack precedence **/
    private static final int[] isp = {0, 19, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 0};
    /** incoming character precedence **/
    private static final int[] icp = {20, 19, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 0};
    /** operators **/
    private static final char[] operators = {'{', '}', '+', '-', '/', '*', '%', ' '};
    private Precedence[] stack;
    private int top;
    private Precedence pop() {
        return stack[top--];
    }
    private void push(Precedence ele) {
        stack[++top] = ele;
    }
    public Precedence getToken(char symbol) {
        switch (symbol) {
        case '('  :
            return Precedence.lparen;
        case ')'  :
            return Precedence.rparen;
        case '+'  :
            return Precedence.plus;
        case '-'  :
            return Precedence.minus;
        case '/'  :
            return Precedence.divide;
        case '*'  :
            return Precedence.times;
        case '%'  :
            return Precedence.mod;
        case ' '  :
            return Precedence.eos;
        default   :
            return Precedence.operand;
        }
    }
    public String postfix(String infix) {
        String postfix = "";
        top = 0;
        stack = new Precedence[infix.length()];
        stack[0] = Precedence.eos;
        Precedence token;
        for (int i = 0; i < infix.length(); i++) {
            token = getToken(infix.charAt(i));
            if (token == Precedence.operand)
                postfix = postfix + infix.charAt(i);
            else if (token == Precedence.rparen) {
                while (stack[top] != Precedence.lparen)
                    postfix = postfix + operators[pop().getIndex()];
                pop();
            }
            else {
                while (isp[stack[top].getIndex()] >= icp[token.getIndex()])
                    postfix = postfix + operators[pop().getIndex()];
                push(token);
            }
        }
        while ((token = pop()) != Precedence.eos)
            postfix = postfix + operators[token.getIndex()];
        return postfix;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        ShuntingYard sy = new ShuntingYard();
        System.out.println("Enter infix expression");
        String infix = scan.next();
        String postfix = sy.postfix(infix);
        System.out.println("\nPostfix expression : " + postfix);
    }
}
```

I tried searching the net and found some working examples like [mathquill](https://mathquill.com) which is a dynamic infix to LaTeX renderer. The problem I am facing while using it in my Java project is that the [project](https://github.com/mathquill/mathquill) is written in javascript and i dont want to implement rhino/nashorn script engines to do this task since it is making it very heavy. Also, I am more than satisfied using a static converter which takes the full input at a time and then returns the full output.

Another resource I found was [this](https://www.kabipan.com/densan/rpnedit2/rpnedit.html) which converts postfix(RPN) to LaTeX code, the problem I am facing is still the same, it is implemented in javascript and using it in Java will be hard.

### What I exactly need

(In order of preference)

- A java library/module which can help me do this (or)
- A pseudo code/logic which can help me go forward (or)
- Guidance/tutorial to implement the above mentioned .js projects into my Java project (A possible option is to access the webpage through my code and pass requests, but that will make my project very dependant)

*Relevant Github project(not mine)

Comment: If you edit the question to include the shunting yard code we can help change it so it generates latex

Comment: @Joni oh okay I will do that